# what's the difference between mount point /sdcard & /sd-ext in recovery.fstab

Tags: file-system, linux, mount, partitions, terminal

This is the recovery.fstab

```
# mount point   fstype    device        [device2]

/boot       mtd         boot
/cache      ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p39
/data       ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p40
/misc       mtd         /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
/recovery   mtd         /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
/sdcard     vfat        /dev/block/mmcblk0p1        /dev/block/mmcblk0
/system     ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p38
/sd-ext     ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
```

What actually made me confused is , /sdcard has device & device2 while others don't.
And I wanna know , which is my Micro SD-CARD, sd-ext / sdcard?
and what is device2 ?